# C ByteBeat dynamically allocated array not working

Tags: arrays, c

I tried to play ByteBeat in C with a dynamically allocated array, I've been searching for 3 or more days to find an answer but no luck... I tried: malloc, HeapAlloc & HeapFree, new datatype & delete.

Here is my code:

```
    std::cout << "Enter duration:" << std::endl;
    int duration;
    std::cin >> duration;

    HWAVEOUT hwo = 0;
    WAVEFORMATEX wfx = { WAVE_FORMAT_PCM, 1, 8000, 8000, 1, 8, 0 };
    
    waveOutOpen(&hwo, WAVE_MAPPER, &wfx, 0, 0, CALLBACK_NULL);

    char* buffer = (char*)malloc(8000 * duration * sizeof(char));
    
    for (int t = 0; t < sizeof(buffer); t++) {
        buffer[t] = t * (t >> 7);
    }

    WAVEHDR whdr = { (LPSTR)buffer, sizeof(buffer), 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0 };

    waveOutPrepareHeader(hwo, &whdr, sizeof(WAVEHDR));
    waveOutWrite(hwo, &whdr, sizeof(WAVEHDR));
    waveOutUnprepareHeader(hwo, &whdr, sizeof(WAVEHDR));
    waveOutClose(hwo);

    Sleep(1000 * duration);
    free(buffer);
```

When I try to make it: `char buffer[8000 * 3]`, it works. Yes, I also did `#pragma comment(lib, "winmm.lib")`
**Please do not tell me to use constant!**

Comment: `t % 13 / 41` this will always be zero because `t % 13` results in a number smaller than 41

Comment: `scanf("%s", duration);`.. `duration` is not a string.

Comment: There's also absolutely zero error checking.  When your `scanf()` call failed to return a sane value in `duration` your code just ignored any possible problem.

Comment: The problem is just I can't use `malloc()`

Comment: And now `scanf("%d", duration);`???  You're randomly changing things hoping to fix your problem.  That's not going to work.  Have you enabled **all** your compiler warnings, read all of then, and put tried to actually understand what they say?

Comment: the scanf is just an example, im using std::cout and std::cin

Comment: @DominikZN please define "not working". What exactly happens if you use `malloc`? Does it not compile? Does it just do nothing? Does it crash? If it crashes, did you use your debugger for investigation? Could you show a [mcve]? What is "bytebeat"?

Comment: It does nothing. Bytebeat is music generated from short math equalations in C.

Comment: just leave this place now its solved and @MartinJames i use C++ but people say my code is C

Comment: `malloc` is largely a `C` function; consider using the `new` operator, instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a classic. The problem is here:

With `char buffer[100]`, `sizeof(buffer)` is 100. With `char *buffer = ....`,  `sizeof(buffer)` is the size of a pointer on your platform (4 or 8).

So just use `WAVEHDR whdr = { (LPSTR)buffer, 8000 * duration, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0 }` instead of `WAVEHDR whdr = { (LPSTR)buffer, sizeof(buffer), 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0 }`.

You should learn how to use your debugger, you could have found out this yourself in a matter of minutes.